How do you customize the Group column header in Vuetify 3?
When using VDataTable in Vuetify 3, when you use the group-by prop a column called Group is added as the first column of the table.
Is there any way to change its name and positioning? The documentation is currently unclear on this.

I think you can achieve this by using slot group.header:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-group-header
<template v-slot:[`group.header`]="{}">
  <th>
    xxx
  </th>
  
</template>

